# How to change the attributes of a HTML element in emberJS from the afterModel or some similar method

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a route and a corresponding template in my ember application. On page load itself I want to hide few elements based on URL parameter. I tried doing this in the afterModel method using jquery `$.("elementName").hide();` and few other combinations. But nothing works because it seems the DOM Is not yet available. The same can be achieved as a button action in the actions section, but it doesn't help me as I would like to do it on page load. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong .

Comment: You can probably use`didInsertElement`. But that is not Ember-like. Instead, why not hide the elements by default and turn them on when you need them?

Comment: @torazaburo that is what I did and it worked. I had to use the hook didTransition and 'after-render'. But the ideal method would be to use helper as mentioned below , I will try it out in my morning and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I guess you could use the "didTransition" Event inside your route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use ember and the handlebars `{{#if}}` helper. If you combine this with `queryParams` its pretty easy:

Your controller can look like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['showSomething'],
});
```

And your template like this:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
{{#if showSomething}}
  <div id="something">something</div>
{{/if}}
```

---

If you *really* want to manually manipulate the DOM you can do this in the `didInsertElement` hook. However you have this *only in a component*:

so the `my-component.hbs` could look like this:

```
<div id="{{concat elementId "something"}}>something</div>
```

and your `my-component.js`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    this._super();
    if(false) {
      $(`#${this.get('elementId')}something`).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

However, I strongly recommend against that!

Comment: What is the purpose of this._super(), why do you recommend against this approach? I resolved this in the route itself by using didTransition and afterRender. I referred the following link : https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/is-there-an-event-after-the-template-has-been-added-to-the-outlet/8737.  One more thing is that I don't have a controller in my app as of now. I guess I could add it, but I am not sure if it's needed.i am waiting for tomorrow to try out your approach.

Comment: Checkout [this link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_overriding-parent-class-methods). `this._super()` is calling the overwritten method. And I do recommend the first approach because its the only eberish way to do that. If you do this manually, you basically work against the framework. Also doing this in the route is not supported behavior I think.Ember could decide to rerender the component at any time. Also if you use handlebars the node will actually be removed from the DOM,and so this will increase the performance. Also why wouldn't use this way?

Answer (score 0):

Are your URL parameters queryParams on the route? If so you can set properties on your controller to check the presence of them (or any other truthy condition) and utilize those in your template for DOM display purposes. You can even send those values to child components.

routes/index.js

```
queryParams: {
  q: {
    refreshModel: true
  },
  colors: {
    refreshModel: true
  }
}
```

controllers/index.js

```
q: '',
colors: [],
hasSearch: Ember.computed.notEmpty('q'), 
hasColors: Ember.computed.notEmpty('colors')
```

templates/index.hbs

```
{{#if hasSearch}}
  <p>You are searching for {{q}}</p>
{{/if}}
// .. etc for colors
```